# How to distribute/allocate tasks from a hostprocess in Python with MPI4PY

Tags: python, mpi, mpi4py

**Scenario**:
I have a program which can be called with multiple processes i.e. multiple cores/MPI ranks.

In its current state, the program for each rank has a loop over a constant value (scalar), which I can write in the source code before starting.

**Example:**
If I choose to run it with "4" as scalar , the main part of the program runs 4 times on each rank. With 4 ranks it would run 16 times, while every rank has had 4 tasks each.

At the end I am gathering the outputs of each process/rank into one concatenated array on rank 0.
So I would get a list of e.g. 16 outputted elements.

**Problem:**
It can happen that one rank has finished its tasks before another one has finished. And therefore one rank could be idle, while the other ranks still have a full queue to do and could distribute scheduled tasks on the idle rank.
I need a solution how I can use MPI to distribute tasks when one rank is idle.
As above:
When one rank has all 4 jobs completed, and another one still has 3 to go, then the open tasks should be distributed to the idle rank.

**What I need**:
I need a hostprocess to distribute the tasks, I need to know how to check for idle ranks and I need to know how to communicate this inbetween the ranks. Also I don't know yet how I can change my scalar as input to something that can be dynamically changed by distribution. E.g. when one rank has one less task to do (so be it 3 in total) because one rank was idle, then it shouldn't have a full for-loop of 4 remaining.

**Pseudocode**:

```
    tasks = 4
    comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
    rank = comm.Get_rank()          # current used core/process
    
    for i in range(tasks):
       //complete task
       output = do something

    output_gathered = comm.gather(output, root = 0)
```

The for loops content can differ in runtime in the real program.

Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. The manager/worker model is usually not a good match for MPI.
2. Is the number "4" just an example? It sounds much too low for the overhead of MPI to be worth it.

But if you really have to:

- let the manager send data (or some type of work descriptor) to a worker, then post an `MPI_Irecv` for that worker.
- then do a `MPI_Waitany` to see which worker finishes,
- receive that result, and send a new work descriptor to the worker.

Comment: 4 is just an example but the true number is not bigger than 100. E.g. 16 cores x 100 = 1600 outputs. The runtime for each task however can vary wildly from essentially 0 to 3-4 hours.
You are speaking of the overhead, when I integrate the host communication, right?

Comment: Ok, with that much runtime don't worry about overhead. Do as I suggested.

Comment: As a beginner, I really don't get it in my mind how to practically implement it with mpi4py. I just want to have the shown "for loop" distributed. And it just has to be something like a for loop in the host process then. I know it is probably done in 10 lines of code but I don't get how to do it, especially what to change for my gather function then, if it even has to change.

Comment: "I just want to have the shown "for loop" distributed." Never use the word "just". You can not "just" do this. Any simple distribution of the for loop will run into serious load imbalance. You need to make it dynamic. Learn about `MPI_Irecv` and such.

Comment: I solved it differently now because even after reading into it, I wasn't able to do it. I am appending results to one file. 1 Line is 1 results. Every rank opens this file and reads the current linecount and depending on it, it terminates or goes on. The I/O overhead in this case is neglectable compared to the runtime of the other stuff.